# How define hook lifecycle dynamically with AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot, angular-decorator

I use a custom decorator in order to add procces at hook [ngAfterViewInit] dynamically. If this hook doesn't exist in the component I modify the prototype in order to add it.

```
export function MyHook(names: string[]) {
return (target: any) => {
    const originalNgAfterViewInit: Function = target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit;

    target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit = () => {

       console.log("Do this before");
       
       if (originalNgAfterViewInit) {
           originalNgAfterViewInit.call(target);
       }

    }
    return target;
};}
```

It works in JIT mode but in AOT mode, I must define a method ngAfterViewInit in the component in order to this code works.

1.**This code works in AOT mode and JIT mode:**

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "my-comp",
templateUrl: "my.component.html"
})
@MyHook(["test"])
export class MyComponent {
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Do this before
>
> Hello

2.**This code works only in JIT mode. Doesn't work in AOT mode:**

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "my-comp",
templateUrl: "my.component.html"
})
@MyHook(["test"])
export class MyComponent {
}
```

No output. But we expect: "Do this before"

Why? And how to resolve this problem?

I use Angular 2.4